# Display price including tax

Tags: price, magento-1, tax, catalog-price-rules

Currently we use this code to display the price of products on our homepage. But this does load the price excluding tax.

How can I edit the code that the price will be including tax?

```
<?php
$first_amount_before_split = substr($_product->getPrice(), 0, -2);
$my_array = explode(".", $first_amount_before_split);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
    <span class="sticker-wrapper top-right home">
        <span class="sticker prijs">
            <span class="main-price"><?php echo $my_array[0]; ?>,</span>
            <span class="sub-price"><?php echo $my_array[1]; ?></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

**EDIT:**

The price is displaying including tax with this code.
But it skips the last 0's. So $49,90 becomes $49,9
How can I display 2 decimals

```
<?php $first_amount_before_split = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()); 
$my_array = explode(".", $first_amount_before_split); ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in you phtml file.

```
$_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')
                      ->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
```

Comment: Thanks! I edit my new code, do you know the solution to this?

Comment: echo number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), '2', '.', ',')

Comment: How does the entire line look like?
This? $first_amount_before_split = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), '2', '.', ',');

Comment: $first_amount_before_split = number_format($this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()), '2', '.', ',')

Comment: hope this worked... ? if so upvote comment also for others reference or edit your question with final answer....

Comment: One last question! Currently prices above 1000 are displayed as 1,525,25. How can I change the first , to a dot. So that the price will be 1.525,25?

Comment: why do you want to do that ?  anyway a simple string replace with php will suffice to do that, replace only first occurance...

Comment: I don't really understand it. What do I need to change in the code? I want that because in our country we use a dot symbol(.) for numbers above 1.000 to separate them

Comment: Here you go.....<?
// pattern, replacement, string, limit
echo preg_replace('/,/', '.', $first_amount_before_split , 1); 
?>

Comment: So it will become this?

<?php $first_amount_before_split = number_format($this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()), '2', '.', ',');  $my_array = explode('/,/', '.', $first_amount_before_split , 1);?>

Answer (score 5):

you can do this by tax helper

```
$_priceInclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_finalPrice, true,
            null, null, null, null, null, false);
```

Here `$_finalPrice=$_product->getFinalprice()`

**Original:**

```
 public function getPrice($product, $price, $includingTax = null, $shippingAddress = null, $billingAddress = null,
                             $ctc = null, $store = null, $priceIncludesTax = null, $roundPrice = true)
    {



   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
   float $price inputed product price
   bool $includingTax return price include tax flag
   null|Mage_Customer_Model_Address $shippingAddress
   null|Mage_Customer_Model_Address $billingAddress
   null|int $ctc customer tax class
   null|Mage_Core_Model_Store $store
   bool $priceIncludesTax flag what price parameter contain tax
  return  float
```

Comment: Thanks! I edit my new code, do you know the solution to this?

Comment: please change last false to true

Comment: Tried that, with your code. But when set last false to true, the price will be display as $49,9 instead of $49,9012

Comment: This helped me, I needed to add 'true' as third parameter, otherwise is worked only sometimes :)